# xcopy all folders and subfolders from txt(with paths , and spaces )

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a txt file with the full path for .jpg files, I need to xcopy the whole folders including everything inside using xcopy using batch file

Comment: you have got a list of files. Which folders you want to copy? give an example.

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question, but I had the same question and neither of the above answers quite did it for me. I had to add `/s`:

```
xcopy C:\path\to\source\directory D:\path\to\destination\ /e /i /y /s
```

That copys all files, subfolders, and files in subfolders. More (and helpful) documentation available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Comment: Updated docs link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Answer (score 2):

`xcopy /?` will show you the options you can use. You probably want something like `xcopy C:\path\to\source\directory D:\path\to\destination\ /e /i /y`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (c:\temp\paths.txt) DO xcopy "%%i*.jpg" "C:\test\" /s /y
```